# Retrieving db.Property choices

Tags: google-app-engine, properties

Searching on the documentation provided by google and browsing SO I haven't found a way to retrieve the choices set on a db.Property object (I want to retrieve it in order to create forms based on the model).

I'm using the following recipe to do what I need, Is this correct? Is there any other way of doing it? (simpler, more elegant, more pythonic, etc.)

For a model like this:

```
class PhoneNumber(db.Model):
    contact = db.ReferenceProperty(Contact,
                               collection_name='phone_numbers')
    phone_type = db.StringProperty(choices=('home', 'work'))
    number = db.PhoneNumberProperty()
```

I do the following modification:

```
class PhoneNumber(db.Model):
    _phone_types = ('home', 'work')
    contact = db.ReferenceProperty(Contact,
                               collection_name='phone_numbers')
    phone_type = db.StringProperty(choices=_phone_types)
    number = db.PhoneNumberProperty()

    @classmethod
    def get_phone_types(self):
        return self._phone_types
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `PhoneNumber.phone_type.choices`.  If you want you could make that into a class method too:

```
@classmethod
def get_phone_types(class_):
    return class_.phone_type.choices
```

You can decide if you prefer the class method approach or not.

Don't forget about Python's [dir](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir) built-in!  It is very useful when exploring objects.

Comment: I totally missed using dir.! Thanks.

Comment: In ndb the attribute seems to be `_choices`.